# pop the first N elements

Tags: python, python-3.x

I've looking for about an hour now how to pop more than one element, at this point i'm thinking a one-liner doesn't exist but i wanna be sure.

What I want:

```
list = [1, 2, 3, 4]
eles = list.pop(2)
# list becomes [3, 4]
# eles = [1, 2]
```

Comment: Be careful how much you pop from the front of list. This requires moving the entire data structure in memory (and slicing can require extra allocations). It's better to use a [deque](https://docs.python.org/3/library/deque) instance instead if you need to modify the front of the list a lot.

Comment: @EdwardMinnix The deque doesn't handle poping multiple elements so the current answer would end up doing the same thing no? And for infos, I'm gonna be popping 4 each time.

Comment: Get things working before worrying about efficiency.

Comment: You came to the conversation 2 days late.

Comment: @Haytam - did you try deque from collection for this ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can try this:

```
l = [1, 2, 3, 4]
eles, l = l[:2], l[2:]
print(eles)
print(l)
```

Output:

```
[1, 2]
[3, 4]
```

Comment: I love it. I believe this doesn't affect the "performance" when the list is big?

Comment: According https://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity#list the complexity of getting slice of list is O(k), so it shouldn't be.

Comment: Slicing a list can be costly in terms of the memory usage (O(k) isn't that bad in terms of speed a hit unless it's in a loop). But slicing a list creates a new list, which can be a significant memory hit if done too often.

Comment: Too often is? I'm gonna be doing this a lot of time to train a neural network xd.

Comment: @EdwardMinnix - I have same use case this one, but like you said I am doing it in loop and it affecting the memory. Do you think, if i use `del` keyword to optimize it? and second point is, I read `deque` is fast `popleft` operation - w hich takes `O(1)` time. instead of list why not deque?

Answer (score 0):

Do this instead:

```
eles = list[:2]
list = list[2:]
```

By the way you should not name a variable `list`, since it shadows the built-in function `list`.

Comment: The naming was just an example, in your example, does the elements get removed from the list?

Comment: Good point. I just updated my answer to update `list` as well.